# R apply with nested loops

Tags: r, performance, loops, matrix, apply

I have a huge data set which I want to perform some operations on. With my current code (shown below) it takes in excess of 3 hours (hasn't finished). I've narrowed it down to this nested loop via some testing on smaller data sets, and need some help using one of the `apply` family of functions to both increase performance (hopefully) and code cleanliness.

```
file <- read.csv("file.csv")
dates <- unique(file$date)
names <- unique(file$name)

data<-c()
mat<-matrix(,nrow=length(dates),ncol=length(names)) # store % change for all names

# loop for every person
for (i in 1:length(names)) { 
  data[[names[i]]] <- file[file$name == names[i],]
  align = 0 # no data for some dates, need alignment score to align later on

  # if this object does not start on the same date as the earliest date we know,
  # then pad this object with a null row at the top
  if (!rownames(mat)[1] %in% data[[names[i]]]$date) {
    data[[names[i]]] <- rbind(c("0000-00-00",0,as.character(data[[names[i]]]$name[1]),NA,FALSE),data[[names[i]]])
  }

  # loop for every date, beginning at 2 because the first date will not be used
  for (j in 2:length(dates)) {
    if (!rownames(mat)[j] %in% data[[names[i]]]$date) {
      mat[j,i] = NA
      align <- align + 1
      next
    }

    current <- as.numeric(data[[names[i]]]$price[j-align])
    previous <- as.numeric(data[[names[i]]]$price[j-1-align])

    # actions based on current and previous cell values
    if (is.na(previous)) { 
      mat[j,i] <- NA
    } else if (current == 0 & previous == 0) {
      mat[j,i] <-  0
    } else if (current == 0) {
      mat[j,i] <- NA 
    } else if (previous == 0) { 
      mat[j,i] <- NA
    } else {
      mat[j,i] <- current/previous-1 
    }
  }
}
```

File looks like:

```
         date id      name price  paid
1  2001-01-01  1  redacted  0.00  TRUE     
2  2001-01-02  2  redacted  0.05  TRUE      
3  2001-01-03  1  redacted 200.0 FALSE
```

**The rundown:**
We loop for every person, storing the data for them in its own position in a list of matrices called `data`. People appear more than once (via ID and Name but we just worry about name for now), which will make up the unique rows of each matrix in `data`.

From here, we check if every each person's date lines up with the earliest known and if not, pad their matrix with one null row.

Now we loop for every date within each person, check if their date lines up to the current one being iterated over (if not, then pad with NA and go next (see below)) and then calculate the % change in how much that person has paid, depending on what the previous value was (0 and NA cause issues so we need `if` statements here) ie. if they paid $20 on 2000-01-01 and $40 on 2000-01-02 then the % change is 100% (appearing as 1) as in they paid double.

So the end result `mat` will look similar to:

```
              redacted    redacted      redacted
2001-01-01          NA          NA            NA          
2001-01-02           1         0.3           0.2       
2001-01-03         0.5           0            NA
```

Can anyone help? I've tried many `apply` variations, none of which seem to work or get me closer to a solution. I know it's a huge read/problem, so any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Seems like I may need nested `apply`, one for each loop?

Thanks!

Comment: I Didn't read the entire post, but i already spotted `data = c()` - Never grow vectors in R, instead pre-allocate the vector to the final size, or some reasonable size: `data = vector(mode = 'list', length = 1000)`. Can you change this and post the results?

Comment: Minor point - avoid calling things `data` since there is a function of the same name `?data`

Comment: I doubt you will get an answer to this unless you give some workable size example data with dummy names e.g. `dput(head(yourdata,50))` AND the expected output you get when you run your function against `head(your data,50)` ... as its extremely difficult to follow your "rundown" especially when the results columns are all redacted. Put yourselves in our shoes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, though it requires several non-base packages:

```
price_diff <- function(x) {  
  zeroes <- sum(which(x == 0))
  if(zeroes == 1) NA else if (zeroes == 2) 0 else x[2] / x[1] - 1
}
file.dt <- data.table(file)[order(date)]
changes <- file.dt[, list(date, change=rollapply(price, 2, price_diff, align="right", fill=NA)),by=name]
dcast(changes, date ~ name, value.var="change")
```

Results in:

```
#           date          Bat          Kat           Kit
# 1   2013-01-01           NA           NA            NA
# 2   2013-01-02 -0.044461024  0.391059725  0.0806087565
# 3   2013-01-03 -0.114559555 -0.342706723 -0.1174446516
# ... 197 more rows ...
```

This produced the same results as your approach, though I had to make some fixes in yours to get it to run.  This also ran about 20x faster on my 200 day 3 person sample.

What I'm doing here is using `data.table` to split the data by person, and then for each person, using `rollapply` to apply the `price_diff` function to a 2 day window, and finally `data.table` re-assembles this all.  This all happens on the `changes` line of code.  Finally, the `dcast` step is to turn the data into the format you want (no further calculations, just going from long to wide format).

Required packages:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(reshape2)
```

Making data like yours:

```
dt.start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
days <- 200
names <- c("Kat", "Kit", "Bat")
file <- data.frame(
  date=rep(seq(dt.start, length.out=days, by="+1 day"), each=length(names)),
  id=rep(1:length(names), each=days),
  name=rep(names, days),
  price=c(5, 10, 20) + runif(days * length(names), -3, 3),
  paid=sample(c(T, F), days * length(names), replace=T)
)
```

Comment: Thanks BrodieG, this was exactly what I was looking for! Worked like a charm and has easily at least reduced run-time by 4x (with the smallest data set, larger ones have seen 6x-8x increase and I'm sure with all the data we will see huge factor increases). Thanks once again.